# Custom validation on the String RequestBody in controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation

For example I have code:

```
@PatchMapping(value = PATH)
public ResponseEntity<Model> updateA(
        @PathVariable("id") String id,
        @RequestBody String text) {
    Model model = service.update(id, text);
    return ResponseEntity.of(model);
}
```

I want to validate text payload. If it contains some unwanted symbols return 400 code. Of course I can do it with addition method like `boolean isValid(String text)` in the controller, but I want to do with annotation somethis like: `@RequestBody @ValidString String text`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any ready made validator for what you describe above but there's a tutorial here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator on how to create custom validators. Instead of validating a phone number you just validate your string. Steps 1-8 are what you're looking for and would not take long to implement.